# Chartboost latest iOS SDK crashes when using example code

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, chartboost

My iOS game is crashing when using Chartboost, but this wasn't happening 2 days ago, it worked fine then and I haven't changed anything.

I am doing the following:

```
[Chartboost startWithAppId:@"<<AppID>>" appSignature:@"<<Signature>>" delegate:self];

[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
```

I have removed the AppID and Signature for security reasons, but in my code they are the correct values

This crashes with the error:

```
2014-06-13 10:09:53.655 3D Line[7903:890b] -[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17801e200
2014-06-13 10:09:53.684 3D Line[7903:890b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17801e200'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18324af50 0x18f7541fc 0x18324fc04 0x18324d930 0x18316d5dc 0x1001dcf14 0x1001cc430 0x1001cecd0 0x1001cf0d4 0x18fd2c014 0x18fd2bfd4 0x18fd31654 0x18fd2bfd4 0x18fd332b8 0x18fd334fc 0x18fec16bc 0x18fec154c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I think it is to do with the JSON sent back from Chartboost. Is this happening for anyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just released a live fix for this. You do not have to update your SDK to get the fix, it's already there :)